# Unexpected result of Pandas.apply() due to having integer as column index

Tags: python, pandas

Let's look at this minimal example:

```
In [208]:
L={'A':[[1,2]],
   'B':[[3,4], [5,6]]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(L), orient="index").stack().reset_index(level=0)
df['val']=None
print 'before apply. \n\n', df
f=lambda x: [x[0], x[1][0], x[1][1]]
print '\nafter apply. \n\n', df.apply(f, axis=1)

before apply. 

  level_0       0   val
0       A  [1, 2]  None
0       B  [3, 4]  None
1       B  [5, 6]  None

after apply. 

  level_0  0  val
0  [1, 2]  1    2
0  [3, 4]  3    4
1  [5, 6]  5    6
```

Strange! The `lambda` function is supposed to return a `list` for each row: for the 1st row, the resultant should be `['A', 1, 2]`, therefore, the expected behavior of `apply()` should be:

```
  level_0  0  val
0       A  1  2
0       B  3  4
1       B  5  6
```

Is there something that I misunderstood about `apply()`?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have column with name `0` (as integer) so `x[0]` means "get from column named `0`" , not from column number 0. But there is no column named `1` so `x[1]` means "get from column number 1".

Try to use `x['level_0']`

```
f=lambda x: [x['level_0'], x[1][0], x[1][1]]
```

or rename columna `0` to string `"0"`

Answer (score 1):

in-line comments:

```
>>> ts = df.iloc[0,]  # take the first row as an example
>>> ts
level_0         A
0          [1, 2]
val          None
Name: 0, dtype: object
>>> ts[0]  # `0` is in the index, so it resolves to item with `index` 0
[1, 2]
>>> ts[1]  # one is not in the index, so it resolves to ts.iloc[1]
[1, 2]
>>> ts[1][0] # (ts.iloc[1])[0]
1
>>> ts[1][1] # (ts.iloc[1])[1]
2
```

moral of the story: do not use integer values as the column names

Comment: `morale of the story` is the best :)

Comment: Good point. `0` index is actually from the `stack()` step, so that part sucks. But I guess some renaming will get thing right.